# Make public class open internally but closed externally kotlin

Tags: kotlin, public

I have a public abstract class which I want other classes in the module to extend, but I do not want to to be extendible externally.
I am aware I could make it sealed, but it has many subclasses and would be cumbersome to have them all in the same file. How can this be achieved?

Comment: That's where `sealed` classes are used!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define its constructor as `internal`.  Subclasses must call the superclass' constructor, so only files that can see that constructor will be able to subclass your class.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it `sealed`, but declare just one `internal` (and not `sealed`) subclass in the same file. Then other classes in the module can see and extend the internal subclass, and so your original class.

> [Note that classes which extend subclasses of a sealed class (indirect inheritors) can be placed anywhere, not necessarily in the same file.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html)

EDIT: the drawback is that the extending classes must also be `internal` (or even less visible). Louis Wasserman's solution avoids this and is simpler.